# PAT with multiple VLAN

Tags: cisco, vlan, nat, packet-tracer

I've set up a network with 4 VLAN, 3 VLAN configured PAT on it and 1 VLAN configured STATIC NAT. The router is acting as the DHCP server. Outside of my router I have another router acting as "the internet" with an ip address of 172.16.10.1 /24.

Everything is working fine and I can successfully do STATIC NAT on VLAN1 however it doesn't work when I attempt PAT configuration on VLAN2, VLAN3 & . Below is my Router configuration:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1578 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
username admin password 0 123
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524C1YC-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 1
ip domain-name test.com
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 1 in
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 ip address 100.10.10.1 255.255.255.240
 ip nat outside
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
!
ip nat pool route 100.10.10.100 100.10.10.100 netmask 255.255.255.240
ip nat inside source list 1 pool route overload
ip nat inside source static 192.168.2.254 100.10.10.3 
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 100.10.10.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
!
!
end
```

Thanks

Comment: ACL "1" is not defined.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want use VLAN 3 & VLAN 4 as your LAN network and  want to configure pat natting for internet access, and assuming VLAN 1 is used for DMZ network for hosting an application which needs static NAT.

Configuration of subinterface in router. For example in router subinterface configuration:

```
Int g0/0.3
Encapsulation dot1Q 3
Ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
Ip nat inside
No shutdown

Int g0/0.4
Encapsulation dot1Q 4
Ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.25&.0
Ip nat inside 
No shutdown
```

**PAT (port address translation)**

Port address translation is always outbound traffic

```
Router(config) access-list 1 permit ip 192.168.2 .0 0.255.255.255
Router(config) access-list 1 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.255.255.255
Router(config) ip nat inside source list 1 interfàce serial 0/1/0 overload
```

PAT is source natting.  The source private IP is translated to the address of interface S0/1/0  when traffic is going from inside to outside (outbound traffic).

**Static NAT configuration for accessing DMZ hosted servers application from internet:**

Assume the internal server is on VLAN1 and assume IP is 192.168.0.5:

Public IP from ISP is: 100.10.10.5

```
Router(config)# ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.5 100.10.10.5
```

Static NAT is considered as destination NAT mostly..